# .PNG seem to work in some Browsers but not in all

Tags: error-handling, web, png

I have a own website which does have a "Webcam like" image which is getting replaced by a newer photo every 5 min automatically. The Picture is a .PNG

So now to the Problem:
Althought the Picture apears on some of my Friends Browsers which are all IE 8 or IE 9 (because of the fact that they all have to use Company PC's they don't have another option) it does only a red cross appear on some of my friends computer. The Strange thing is, that even when my friend does have the exactly same Version of the IE, on my PC it does work (also on alot other computers) it does not work on his... does anyone have an idea why this error occures and a way to fix it?

here is the code example

```
    <div class="webcam_container">
       <img src="\\smef05/c-files/0_Member/Faebu_TEMP/YAWcam/image000000.png" alt="alternative text blabla" style="position:absolute; margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 500px; bottom: 0;" />
    </div>
```

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Comment: I just edited the question althrough that I don't think it will help u alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens with me in my office. e.g. in the SO website the images get served from a different domain. Apparently the firewalls block that domain and thus images appear as x mark in all browsers.

If you are not using a different domain for the images few companies might have blocked the images for some wiered reasons. This can be easily tested by asking your friends (for whom the images does not load) to copy the image url and pasted in a new browser tab / window and look for what HTTP code do they get there. It would certainly give you a good hint to troubleshoot further.

Comment: @Silva Senthil
Thanks you are on the right track :) it seems that his browser ain't able to load the picture somehow... the error message is like follow(translated by me because the message is in german):"The file //path/Temp_pictures/image.png was not found. Please check the spelling and retry the process."
But why is almost 2/3 of my company able to see the picture while he ain't? 
Do you have any sugestions how i could fix this problem?

Comment: That might be because of the network share - "\\smef05" is not accessible for those users. You can ask the users who are unable to get the image to copy the path "\\smef05/c-files/0_Member/Faebu_TEMP/YAWcam/image000000.png" and paste in their run window (Windows Key + R) and see what is the message. If it says any error you know for sure they can not access the network drive.                                                              EDIT - I would suggest hosting images in a web server like IIS if you are using ASP.NET or apache if you are using any open source for development.

Comment: THANKS! the problem was the accessiblity for the other users because they aren't allowed to access the ../0_Member path. I know I should use a webserver like ISS but sadly the tool which I use to take the photos does strangly not support the upload to a webserver (might be because of blocked ports...)